# Countdown Timer with Pause and Stop buttons in Swift

Tags: swift, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I’m trying to figure out a way to create a countdown timer in Swift that I can pause, stop and resume.

This is my code:

```
@objc func updateTimer() {
    if secondsPassed < totalTime {
        secondsPassed += 1
        progressBar.progress = Float(secondsPassed) / Float(totalTime)
        
        let minutes = String(totalTime / 60)
        let seconds = String(totalTime % 60)
        countDownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
        totalTime -= 1
        
    } else {
        timer.invalidate()
        titleLabel.text = "Done!"
        
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "alarm_sound", withExtension: "mp3")
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        player.play()
    }
    
}
```

I already have a progress bar, but I can’t set up the countdown timer properly. When I run this code, I get 0:3 instead of 0:03. Another problem is that it doesn’t stop at 0:00. It just freezes before that.

Here’s the entire code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    // testando countdownlabel
    @IBOutlet weak var countDownLabel: UILabel!
    
    let eggTimes = ["Soft": 3, "Medium": 4, "Hard": 5]
    var totalTime = 0
    var player: AVAudioPlayer!
    var secondsPassed = 0
    var timer = Timer()
    
    @IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        timer.invalidate()
        let hardness = sender.currentTitle!
        totalTime = eggTimes[hardness]!
        progressBar.progress = 0.0
        secondsPassed = 0
        titleLabel.text = hardness
        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func updateTimer() {
        if secondsPassed < totalTime {
            secondsPassed += 1
            progressBar.progress = Float(secondsPassed) / Float(totalTime)
            
            let minutes = String(totalTime / 60)
            let seconds = String(totalTime % 60)
            countDownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
            totalTime -= 1
            
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
            titleLabel.text = "Done!"
            
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "alarm_sound", withExtension: "mp3")
            player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
            player.play()
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: you should never rely on a timer to measure elapsed time. Get the start Date and check the time interval since now

Comment: Btw you can use DateComponentsFormatter positional style to display your string properly formatted (as well as localized)